# Create unique sequence for row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a few thousand rows of data and need to create the unique sequences for each. Here is an example (each value is in its own cell):

```
Text1| Text2| Text2| Text2| Text3| Text3| Text1|
```

I need to create the unique sequence to look sometime like this

```
Text1| Text2| Text3| Text1|    or
Text1,Text2,Text3,Text1|
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In VBA ok? or just formulas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first `Text1` is in A1, then:

```
=A1&","&IF(A1<>B1,B1&",","")&IF(B1<>C1,C1&",","")&IF(C1<>D1,D1&",","")&IF(D1<>E1,E1&",","")&IF(E1<>F1,F1&",","")&IF(F1<>G1,G1,"")
```

might be worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

As a user defined function

```
Public Function ClarkeyCat2(ByRef rng As Range, delimIT As String, Optional ByVal trimIT As Boolean = False) As Variant
Dim c As Range
Dim UniqueColl As Collection
Dim tmpValue As Variant
Set UniqueColl = New Collection


If Not trimIT Then

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each c In rng
        If (c.Value <> "") Then
            UniqueColl.Add c.Value, c.Value
        End If
    Next

    For k = 1 To UniqueColl.Count
        ClarkeyCat2 = ClarkeyCat2 & IIf(ClarkeyCat2 = "", "", delimIT) & UniqueColl.Item(k)
    Next
Else
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each c In rng
        If (c.Value <> "") Then
            tmpValue = Trim(c.Value)
            UniqueColl.Add tmpValue, tmpValue
        End If
    Next

    For k = 1 To UniqueColl.Count
        ClarkeyCat2 = ClarkeyCat2 & IIf(ClarkeyCat2 = "", "", delimIT) & UniqueColl.Item(k)
    Next
End If

End Function
```

Use like this

[image]

**Update** Updated to optionally strip extraneous white space from cell entries, before deciding if entries are unique. Default behaviour is to not strip white space. Set using the optional Boolean third parameter.

Comment: Its overkill if you just want a formula. But its usable in other situations.

Comment: I do love vba solutions, and this could be useful in the future. One problem though, its doesn't work in the following situation.

    Text1| Text2| Text2| Text1| Text1| Text1| Text1|

Comment: @MichaelCarn-Bennett thanks. I assumed the "|" signified the separation between cells. Are you saying that the "|" is actually part of the text string, in each cell? If you could be a bit more descriptive (as to what Text1| Text2| actually means, I can fix it up.

Comment: I guess you mean extra white space, as in "Text1| " not equal to "Text1|". If so, I updated the function to work in that case using an optional third *true/false* argument. Default is *false*.

Comment: @pnuts thanks. I saw OPs example - but I thought when the OP said "unique sequence", two times, I thought they meant a .... unique sequence...contrary to example. Oh well. That will learn me to "ReadTheFQuestion" :-). Ta

Comment: A hard one to explain! But you both understand it now :)
Many thanks to you both.